# Axiomatic proof help?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Can anyone help me to prove this using only the axioms?

" If **a** is a positive real number which is less than the real number **b**, then the negative of the reciprocal of **a** is less than the negative of the reciprocal of **b**."

Comment: What thoughts do you have on this? Which axioms are you allowed to use?

Comment: You have to explain what "axioms" you're referring to. Moreover, homework questions have their own etiquette.

Comment: There are the axioms I can use : 
1.) For all x,y∈ R, x.y= y.z 
2.) For all x,y,z ∈ R, (xy).z = x.(yz) 
3.) For all x ∈ R, (-1).x = -x 
4.) For all x,y ∈ R, x<y, iff -y<-x 
5.) For each x∈ R, x≠0, there is a unique real number 1/x such that x.(1/x)=1

Answer (score 1):

This is how the proof would go if you know the field axioms of the real numbers. For a general field $F$ the reciprocal is the multiplicative inverse denoted $x^{-1}$ but for $\mathbb{R}$ the multiplicative inverse lives in the field of fractions of $\mathbb{R}$. Please only use this if you know these properties. I can make edits if you explain which axioms you do have.

$\mathbb{R}$ is a field

$(1)$ You know if $x>y$ then $\dfrac{1}{x}<\dfrac{1}{y}$ for $x,y \not = 0$

$(2) \ a,b \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$

$(3) \ a<b \Rightarrow a-b<0 \Rightarrow -1(a-b)>0 \Rightarrow -a-(-b)>0 \Rightarrow -a+b>0 \Rightarrow -a>-b$

$(4)$ Apply statement $(1)$ to the last inequality.